# Applying AdS-CFT to traversable wormholes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, string-theory, ads-cft, wormholes

ER=EPR recently brought up the connection between non-traversable wormholes and entanglements. What about traversable wormholes? Can we apply AdS/CFT to traversable wormholes?

Comment: What's a traversable wormhole? Where can I get one?

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question. Traversable wormholes are wormholes that admit timelike trajectories through them (though the spacetime may be unstable or have some other unpleasant property). An example of a non-traversable wormhole is the bifurcation surface of a static black hole which connects two asymptotic regions through a spacelike surface. Traversable wormholes showed up in the context of AdS/CFT in this recent paper: http://inspirehep.net/record/1394880, where properties of the CFT were used to rule out traversable wormholes.